# Delphi Indy CookieManager Wordpress Login

Tags: wordpress, delphi, authentication, indy

The problem is that when I press the login button I get this in the memo: "Your session has expired. You can log in again from this page or go to the login page". I'm using XE3. Thanks for your help

```
var
  tslPost1: TStringList;
  sResult1: String;
  idhHttp1: TIdHTTP;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tslPost1 := TStringList.Create;
  idhHttp1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  idhHttp1.HandleRedirects := True;
  idhHttp1.AllowCookies := True;
  idHttp1.CookieManager := Form1.IdCookieManager1;
  idhHttp1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0)      Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
try
  tslPost1.Add('log=' + Edit1.Text);
  tslPost1.Add('pwd=' + Edit2.Text);
  tslPost1.Add('rememberme=forever');
  tslPost1.Add('wp-submit=Login');
  tslPost1.Add('redirect_to=' + Edit3.Text + '/wp-admin/');
  tslPost1.Add('testcookie=1');

  idhHttp1.Get(Edit3.Text + '/wp-login.php');
  idhHttp1.Post(Edit3.Text + '/wp-login.php', tslPost1);

  sResult1 := idhHttp1.Get(Edit3.Text + '/wp-admin/');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(sResult1);
finally
  FreeAndNil(tslPost1);
  FreeAndNil(idhHttp1);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Hard to diagnose without seeing the actual website involved and/or the actual HTTP requests/responses. Have you tried debugging the code? There are multiple possible failure points: 1) the cookie is not issued by the server, 2) the cookie is not accepted by TIdCookieManager, 3) the cookie is not sent back to the server, 4) the server is ignoring the cookie, 5) the cookie is really expired. #2 and #3 are typical culprits. Another possibility is if the server requires a `Referer` header that you are not sending.

Answer (score 0):

pls try adding the cookie manually:

```
CookieManager.AddServerCookie('wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check',
    TIdURI.Create(Website));
```

or a complete login function:

```
function TWordPress.Login(AIdHTTPHelper: TIdHTTPHelper): Boolean;
var
  Params: TStringList;
  Enc: TEncoding;
  ResponseStr: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  with AIdHTTPHelper do
  begin
    AddCookie('wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check', Website);

    Params := TStringList.Create;
    try
      with Params do
      begin
        Add('log=' + AccountName);
        Add('pwd=' + AccountPassword);
        Add('rememberme=forever');

        Add('wp-submit=');
        Add('testcookie=1');
      end;

      Request.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
      Enc := CharsetToEncoding(Request.CharSet);
      try
        try
          ResponseStr := Post(Website + 'wp-login.php', Params, Enc);
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            ErrorMsg := E.message;
            Exit;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Enc.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;

    if (Pos('action=logout', ResponseStr) = 0) then
    begin
      with TRegExpr.Create do
      begin
        try
          InputString := ResponseStr;
          Expression := 'error">(.*?)<\/div>';

          if Exec(InputString) then
          begin
            Self.ErrorMsg := HTML2Text(Match[1]);
            Exit;
          end;
        finally
          Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

here is my uIdHTTPHelper unit.

```
unit uIdHTTPHelper;

interface

uses
  // Delphi
  SysUtils, Classes, Dialogs, StrUtils,
  // Indy
  IdGlobal, IdURI, IdCharsets, IdHTTP, IdCookieManager, IdCookie, IdZLib, IdCompressorZLib, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdSocks, IdMultipartFormData,
  // Plugin System
  uPlugInInterface, uPlugInConst;

type
  TIdHTTPHelper = class(TIdHTTP)
  private
    FLastRedirect: string;

    function GetCookieList: string;
    procedure SetCookieList(ACookies: string);
    function GetResponseRefresh: string;

    procedure Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string; var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: boolean; var VMethod: TIdHTTPMethod);
  protected
    FIdCookieManager: TIdCookieManager;
    FIdCompressorZLib: TIdCompressorZLib;
    FIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    FIdSocksInfo: TIdSocksInfo;
  public
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(const APlugIn: IPlugIn); overload;
    property LastRedirect: string read FLastRedirect;
    procedure AddCookie(ACookie, AWebsite: string);
    procedure Get(AURL: string; AResponseContent: TStream); overload;
    function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TStrings; AByteEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil): string; overload;
    procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource, AResponseContent: TStream); overload;
    procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream; AResponseContent: TStream); overload;
    property CookieList: string read GetCookieList write SetCookieList;
    property Response_Refresh: string read GetResponseRefresh;
    class function Charsets: string;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

function TIdHTTPHelper.GetCookieList: string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      for I := 0 to CookieManager.CookieCollection.Count - 1 do
        Add(CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookies[I].ServerCookie);

      Result := Text;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.SetCookieList(ACookies: string);

  function ExtractUrl(const AURL: string): string;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    I := PosEx('/', AURL, Pos('://', AURL) + 3);
    if I > 0 then
      Result := copy(AURL, 1, I)
    else
      Result := AURL;
  end;

var
  I: Integer;
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      Text := ACookies;
      for I := 0 to Count - 1 do
        AddCookie(Strings[I], ExtractUrl(Request.Referer));
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

function TIdHTTPHelper.GetResponseRefresh: string;
// Ähnlich dem "Location" Header
const
  url = 'url=';
var
  _RefreshHeader: string;
begin
  _RefreshHeader := LowerCase(Response.RawHeaders.Values['Refresh']);
  Result := '';
  if (Pos(url, _RefreshHeader) > 0) then
    Result := copy(_RefreshHeader, Pos(url, _RefreshHeader) + length(url));
end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string; var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: boolean; var VMethod: TIdHTTPMethod);
begin
  FLastRedirect := dest;
end;

constructor TIdHTTPHelper.Create();
begin
  inherited Create(nil);
  FIdCookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
  FIdCompressorZLib := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(nil);
  FIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  FIdSocksInfo := TIdSocksInfo.Create(nil);

  OnRedirect := Redirect;
end;

constructor TIdHTTPHelper.Create(const APlugIn: IPlugIn);
var
  _ICMSPlugin: ICMSPlugIn;
begin
  Create();

  with APlugIn do
    if Proxy.Active then
      if not(Proxy.ServerType = ptHTTP) then
        with FIdSocksInfo do
        begin
          Host := Proxy.Server;
          Port := Proxy.Port;
          if (Proxy.ServerType = ptSOCKS4) then
            Version := svSocks4
          else
            Version := svSocks5;
          Username := Proxy.AccountName;
          Password := Proxy.AccountPassword;

          Enabled := True;
        end
        else
          with ProxyParams do
          begin
            ProxyServer := Proxy.Server;
            ProxyPort := Proxy.Port;
            ProxyUsername := Proxy.AccountName;
            ProxyPassword := Proxy.AccountPassword;
          end;

  FIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.TransparentProxy := FIdSocksInfo;

  CookieManager := FIdCookieManager;
  Compressor := FIdCompressorZLib;
  IOHandler := FIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

  AllowCookies := True;
  HandleRedirects := True;

  ConnectTimeout := APlugIn.ConnectTimeout;
  ReadTimeout := APlugIn.ReadTimeout;

  ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  HTTPOptions := HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol];

  Request.Accept := 'text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1';
  Request.AcceptCharSet := 'iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1';
  Request.AcceptEncoding := 'deflate, gzip, identity, *;q=0';
  Request.AcceptLanguage := 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8';
  Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
  Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  if Supports(APlugIn, ICMSPlugIn) then
  begin
    if APlugIn.QueryInterface(ICMSPlugIn, _ICMSPlugin) = 0 then
      try
        Request.Referer := _ICMSPlugin.Website;
      finally
        _ICMSPlugin := nil;
      end;
  end;
  Request.UserAgent := 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; de) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.51';
  ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.AddCookie(ACookie: string; AWebsite: string);
var
  IdURI: TIdURI;
begin
  IdURI := TIdURI.Create(AWebsite);
  try
    CookieManager.AddServerCookie(ACookie, IdURI);
  finally
    IdURI.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.Get(AURL: string; AResponseContent: TStream);
begin
  try
    inherited Get(AURL, AResponseContent);
  except
    on E: EDecompressionError do
      ;
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      if not(Pos('<body', LowerCase(E.ErrorMessage)) = 0) then
      begin
        if AResponseContent.InheritsFrom(TStringStream) then
          TStringStream(AResponseContent).WriteString(E.ErrorMessage);
      end
      else
        raise ;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TIdHTTPHelper.Post(AURL: string; ASource: TStrings; AByteEncoding: TIdTextEncoding = nil): string;
begin
  try
    Result := inherited Post(AURL, ASource, AByteEncoding);
  except
    on E: EDecompressionError do
      ;
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      if not(Pos('<body', LowerCase(E.ErrorMessage)) = 0) then
        Result := E.ErrorMessage
      else
        raise ;
    end;
  end;
  if SameStr('', Result) then
  begin
    if not(Response.Location = '') then
      Result := Get(Response.Location)
    else if not(Response_Refresh = '') then
      Result := Get(Response_Refresh);
  end;
end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.Post(AURL: string; ASource, AResponseContent: TStream);
begin
  try
    inherited Post(AURL, ASource, AResponseContent);
  except
    on E: EDecompressionError do
      ;
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      if not(Pos('<body', LowerCase(E.ErrorMessage)) = 0) then
      begin
        if AResponseContent.InheritsFrom(TStringStream) then
          TStringStream(AResponseContent).WriteString(E.ErrorMessage);
      end
      else
        raise ;
    end;
  end;
  if AResponseContent.InheritsFrom(TStringStream) and (TStringStream(AResponseContent).DataString = '') then
  begin
    if not(Response.Location = '') then
      Get(Response.Location, AResponseContent)
    else if not(Response_Refresh = '') then
      Get(Response_Refresh, AResponseContent);
  end;
end;

procedure TIdHTTPHelper.Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream; AResponseContent: TStream);
begin
  Assert(ASource <> nil);
  Request.ContentType := ASource.RequestContentType;
  Post(AURL, TStream(ASource), AResponseContent);
end;

class function TIdHTTPHelper.Charsets: string;
var
  Lcset: TIdCharset;
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      for Lcset := TIdCharset(1) to high(TIdCharset) do
        Add(IdCharsetNames[Lcset]);

      Result := Text;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;

destructor TIdHTTPHelper.Destroy;
begin
  FIdSocksInfo.Free;
  FIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Free;
  FIdCompressorZLib.Free;
  FIdCookieManager.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

end.
```